# use init to save multiple entries to a struct (swift4)

Tags: ios, arrays, struct, init, swift4

My code below uses init to save 1 entry to the struct. The problem is that it can only save 1 entry. I need to somehow make this into a array. So I am trying to use a button to submit a string to a struct where the struct can take multiple entires right now it can only take 1.

```
    import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var c: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var a: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) {

  let judo = Person.init(name: a.text ?? "", phone: Int(c.text ?? "") ?? 0)
    }


    struct Person :  CustomStringConvertible  {
        var name: String
        var phone: Int
        static var myStruct = [String]();
        var description: String {
            return   "\(name),\(phone)"
        }}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood that you want persons to be added to array on press of button

Here is the solution

```
var persons:[Person] = [Person]()

    @IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) {
        let judo = Person.init(name: a.text ?? "", phone: Int(c.text ?? "") ?? 0)
        self.persons.append(judo)
    }
```

Hope you are looking for this